# add a function by Tag Name inline like onmouseover when the page loads

Tags: javascript, html

I need to know how to add a function within a Tag, this is important since the IDs and Classes are different and I need to apply the JavaScript method with the same Tag name. So far this is what I have come up with and am trying to get this to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<select>
    <option>1</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select>
    <option>1</option>
</select>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT");
    for (var i = 0;i < elem.length; i++)
    {
        elem[i].onmouseover = "this.style.background='red'";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't you use classes?

Comment: No i can't, even some of the classes are different

Comment: Ok. I can't test your code when on my phone, but found a few things. The `<script>` tag should declare `type=text/javascript`, try changing `"SELECT"` to lowercase letters, and put your JavaScript function within the `<head>` tag and execute it after the DOM loads. Three stabs in the dark, hope it helps :)

Comment: @SimonCarlson None of these things would do much. It is unnecessary to use the type tag, and the placement of the text doesn't matter as long as the dom has loaded

Comment: @CodyGuldner You're right, it's useless to declare the type and case specific tag name ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handlers are functions, so:

```
elem[i].onmouseover = function() {
    this.style.background='red';
}
```

When you add an event handler directly in your HTML, like in `<div onmouseover="this.style.background='red'"></div>`, that wrapper function is implicit. When attaching the handler from JavaScript, it's mandatory, and its body should be regular code, not a string.

Comment: why can't other answers be as straight forward and simple as this. ty bfavaretto :)

Comment: Because some questions lead us to believe we need to teach the asker about *mandatory* stuff like headers, titles, *nothing* before a doc-type declaration, properly defining a script-tag, not getting `elem.length` every single iteration (but putting it in a var outside the loop), etc ...  And because we don't only answer you, but keep future readers in mind to. Nothing wrong with having a multitude of roads that all lead to Rome; people can pick what they like.      :P

Comment: @GitaarLAB Agreed that many answer styles are possible, and useful. However, sometimes too much information may be overwhelming, so I usually prefer to focus on one issue at a time. Here, I interpreted the question as "when I try to set an event handler from js the same way I do when I use an inline html attribute, it fails; why?". I edited my answer to make that more clear.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this

```
window.onload=function(){
    var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("SELECT");
    for (var i = 0;i < elem.length; i++)
    {
        elem[i].onmouseover = function(){ this.style.background='red'; }
        elem[i].onmouseout = function(){ this.style.background='white'; }
    }
};
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/hMPEt/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You might try this (including some fixes in your HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>Demo</title>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
function highlight(){
    this.style.background='red';
}

window.onload=function(){
    var col = document.getElementsByTagName('select'), L=col.length;
    while(L--){ col[L].addEventListener("mouseover", highlight, false); }
};
//]]>  
</script>
</head><body>

<select>
    <option>1</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select>
    <option>1</option>
</select>

</body></html>
```

[Working JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/U9ewj/).

Should you'd want the color to toggle, replace the javascript with something like this:

```
function highlight(){
    var ts=this.style;
    ts.backgroundColor = ts.backgroundColor === 'red' ? '' : 'red';
}

window.onload=function(){
    var col = document.getElementsByTagName('select'), L=col.length;
    while(L--){ 
        col[L].addEventListener("mouseover", highlight, false); 
        col[L].addEventListener("mouseout", highlight, false);
    }
};
```

[Working JSFiddle of that here](http://jsfiddle.net/U9ewj/1/)